# Simple ARP poisoning attack with UNIX?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, security, unix

I would like to know how to do a simple ARP poison attack with UNIX commands only (no ettercap or arpspoof or anything like that.) I don't care about forwarding packets to the actual router, I just want to drop them. I heard that it works by sending fake arp packets to machines that want to know what the router's MAC address is. How could this be done as simply as possible?

Comment: Nothing, because I have no idea how I might go about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Linux and the BSDs (including OS X) diverge, the instructions for how to do this on a given Unix-like OS are also diverging. Here are some instructions for OS X.

1. Find your router's IP address, perhaps by running `netstat -rnaf inet` and looking at the "default" route at the top of the list.
2. Find your router's MAC address, perhaps by running `arp -an` and looking for your router's IP address.
3. Tell your network interface to use your router's MAC address:
   `sudo ifconfig en0 ether 00:11:22:33:44:55`
4. Hope it works. Without purpose-built tools for ARP spoofing, you're at the mercy of your network stack's ARP code. If your network stack has modern ARP code, it might not try to fight to own that MAC address if there's already someone else using it (which there of course will be: your router).

I'm not aware of any widely deployed, "built-in" Unix command-line tools that let you forge custom ARP packets. That's why people install other commands like `arpspoof` and `ettercap`.

In OS X, you can transmit any arbitrary sequence of bytes that you like, by way of the Berkeley Packet Filter kernel facility. Just `open(2)` a `/dev/bpfX` device, use `ioctl(2)` to attach it to an interface like `en0`, and write bytes to it. Each individual write (that is, each buffer of bytes handed off in an individual call to `write(2)`) is transmitted as a packet. But that's a little beyond what you can easily do with a shell script. I think most Unix graybeards would whip up a little C tool to do that. But that's basically reimplementing key functionality of some other well-known ARP-spoofing tool, and in modern Unix environments, it's easier to tell your package manager to install `arpspoof` or `ettercap` or something.

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell me how I might "whip up a little C tool to do that"? I know it will be complicated, so please comment your code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RobertMoore - You would need to attempt to do that yourself, post any questions you have on Stackoverflow, you have no idea what you are asking for.

Comment: @RobertMoore You seem like you may be new to asking complicated technical questions on the Internet. Please read ESR's famously helpful guide, "[How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)".

Comment: Your ifconfig en1 ether worked for ANY mac address except the router's (so my computer can mimic the MAC address of devices on the network, but not the router.) Just wondering, if I set my MAC address to that of a computer on the network, does all traffic go to me, both devices, only the original device, or neither?